# Check if MemberPress exists before add_action call

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have a custom plugin that checks if MemberPress exists in order to present membership only content in a modal dialog box.

Now I want to add a new feature to this plugin where I redirect the user to a different page based on login URL parameters, which I generate from the page the user came from. The problem is, this is achieved through :

```
add_action('mepr-process-login-redirect-url', 'some_mb_function');
```

But if MemberPress is not installed, that class mepr-process-login-redirect-url does not exist.  How do I check to see if MemberPress is installed before making the add_action call?

I did try using the generalized WP call:

```
add_action('login_init', 'some_function');
```

But that is not execute if MemberPress is installed.

Catch 22.  Any ideas?

Comment: You don't really need to worry about this: there's no harm in adding the action if MemberPress isn't installed. It'll never get called, but it won't get in the way.

Comment: Also worth noting that `mepr-process-login-redirect-url` is not a class in this context. It’s just the action name.

Comment: How can it never be called? It is in the main loop.